# NetLogo: Monitor variable of turtle

Tags: netlogo, monitor

I have a breed "robots" and I create a single robot with health 0.

```
breed [robots robot] 
create-robots 1 [
  set health 0
]
```

Now I want to track the robot's health during runtime. I've tried many things like

```
[ health ] of robot 0
```

But it just doesn't seem to work, the monitor just shows "N/A" like below.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code (or the bit you've shown anyway). Have you actually run the procedure that the `create` is inside of? Here's is a complete model:

```
breed [robots robot]
robots-own [health]

to setup
  create-robots 1
  [ set health 0
  ]
end
```

If you have a monitor with `[ health ] of robot 0` it will show N/A initially. As soon as you run the `setup` procedure (with a button call, or from the command center), it changes to 0.

Comment: The problem was that I was creating another breed before the robot (I didn't realize the id was global among all turtles). My bad.